# ActionDrawer/Actionbar weirdness with Spinner

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

I had a Spinner in an actiondrawer, sort of how google play does it, but for some reason when I go to a fragment that is a nested fragment (this is a [SlidingTabs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tRg_eDfQ8fk) Fragment that displays other fragments) the app would not send me the spinner change events after about the 3rd time the Spinner changed.

So since I am short on time I moved the spinner from the ActionDrawer to the ActionBar, and that is even worse as it will never send the event if I am on a page with nested fragments.
[image: Spinner in ActionDrawer]

Both of these solutions work fine when a nonNested fragment is displayed?  What could I be missing?  This app is using the latest ActionBar/ActionDrawer support from Google.  Also, the listener for this Spinner is in the Activity and is established before the nested fragments are displayed.

Some code for the spinner (the system.outs stop showing on the nested fragment page):

```
mActionDrawerSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            System.out.println("---->>>onItemSelected" + !mIsDrawerLocked);
            try {
                Integer previousSelect = (Integer) parent.getTag(TAG_DODGE_ITEM_SELECTEDBUG);
                //for some reason when the Drawer is revealed the first time it emits this event...
                if (previousSelect == null) {
                    parent.setTag(TAG_DODGE_ITEM_SELECTEDBUG, position);
                    System.out.println("---->>>onItemSelected early");
                    return;
                }

                parent.setTag(TAG_DODGE_ITEM_SELECTEDBUG, position);
                handleProxyChanged((PatientAdapterItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position), false);
                mActivitydata.mSelectedProxyIdx = position;
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("onItemSelected---->>>");
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: I think it is a good idea to show us your code!

Comment: Added some although without posting just about everything I don't know if it will help.

Comment: I figured it out.  I needed to setHasOptionsMenu(true) for it before onCreateView time.  I don't understand why this would enable disable response to the spinner listener that is setup outside of this fragment.

Comment: this tells that I (as a fragment) want to manipulate actionbar menu.

Comment: Ok, so I set it to false so shouldn't it go back to the activity...